# Road travel from Cameroon to Angola

Tags: customs-and-immigration, driving, angola, cameroon

Is there a clear road travel means from Cameroon to Angola? This is my first major travel to another African country, and I’m excited as well as curious to know that I’m safe. Are the roads good enough? What is the situation with border officials and their tolerance for tourists without visas?

Comment: According to [Visa policy of Angola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Angola), citizens of Cameroon require a visa to enter Angola. So I would say their "tolerance for tourists without visas" would be very low, if those tourists actually require visas.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking if you can enter Angola by road without a visa?

Comment: Even if the policy is visa free or visa on arrival, "roadside" borders in many African countries are mxnned by corrupt officials so you may be in for a surprise. Drew Binsky (if that's his name) had a taste of this, somewhere in West Africa.

Comment: Yaoundé - Luanda is a 2400 km 35h trek, with two visas to obtain (as a Cameroon citizen, Angola and DRC), and quite dangerous border zones... wouldn't recommend

Comment: What is your citizenship?  Are you a native of Cameroon?

Comment: Nicolas what about Cameroon-Gabon-Republic of Congo and Angola route?

Comment: I’m having a Nigerian passport

Comment: I’m just desperate to see Africa for probably the only time in my lifetime

Comment: I’m only just transiting to Zambia to see Victoria falls. So I assume there won’t be a problem with visas.

Comment: You may be interested in [Visa requirements for Nigerian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Nigerian_citizens). A quick look at the map shows that there is no visa-free overland route for Nigerian citizens from Nigeria to Victoria Falls.